# How to bypass math.clamp (Lua)

Tags: lua

**How do i bypass math.clamp?**

So here is a simple math.clamp script:

```
local number = 10
number = math.clamp(number,1,5) -- This will make the number 5
```

How would i bypass that, so that math.clamp will still make it 10, and not the maximum value.
**And is it possible?**

Comment: sorry but how does this question make sense? if you want number to be 10, assign 10

Answer (score 2):

Well just assign 10 and don't call math.clamp?

Alternatively overwrite math.clamp

```
function math.clamp(number) return number end
```

Comment: I have a script, which sends a number to another script, and the other script, clamps it. I want a way to bypass that clamping function, and no, i can't edit the other script, it's located on the server. The only method than kinda works is doing '0/0'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following straightforward implementation of `math.clamp`:

```lua
function math.clamp(x, min, max)
    if x < min then return min end
    if x > max then return max end
    return x
end
```

`nan` is the only value that won't be clamped correctly, since every operation on `nan` (`nan < min`, `nan > max`) evaluates to `false` - the `if`s won't trigger. Infinities (`math.huge`) behave as expected though.

The somewhat shorter form using `math.min` and `math.max` behaves the same:

```lua
function math.clamp(x, min, max)
    return math.max(math.min(x, max), min)
end
```

since both `math.min` and `math.max` will yield `nan` if any of the inputs are `nan`! So this clamping function will, perhaps unintended, return `nan` if `x` is `nan` (which can be obtained e.g. through `0/0`). This will be the only value outside of the `min`-`max` range you'll be able to get through this function though.

---

Possible `nan`-safe implementations may look as follows:

```lua
function math.clamp(x, min, max)
    if x ~= x then return min end -- explicit nan handling
    if x < min then return min end
    if x > max then return max end
    return x
end
```

or

```lua
function math.clamp(x, min, max)
    if x >= min then
        if x <= max then return x end
        return max
    end
    return min
end
```

both will clamp `nan` to `min` (which is an arbitrary choice).

Comment: Both implementations return `nan`